# Sourcing files using relative paths

Tags: r

Let's say I have this project structure:

```
project/
├─ model-training/
│  ├─ h2o.R
├─ lib/
   ├─ formatter.R
```

in the `h2o.R` file, I would like to source the `formatter.R` using a relative path:

```
source('../lib/formatter.R')
```

rather than the usual way of specifying the full path:

```
source('lib/formatter.R')
```

and then being able to run it from the `project` folder:

```
R -f model-training/bigquery.R
```

but I get the error:

```
cannot open file '../lib/formatter.R': No such file or directory
```

I can get it to work by changing my working directory to the `model-training`.  But really what I would like is the ability to run scripts from the `project` folder and that when I move the `model-training` and `lib` folders around (e.g. putting them into another folder), the `source` lines will not break by the virtue of them being relative. This is why I would like to use relative paths instead of absolute paths from the `project` folder.

(Moderators, I see that there are potentially similar questions asked previously on this forum, however they either don't include a full example, don't use `source`, accept "change the working directory" as the answer - in short, they don't answer my question.)

Answer (score 0):

In the `h2o.R` file you could use:

```
currentDir = dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile)
source(file.path(currentDir, "..","lib","formatter.R"))
```

This will only work if you source `h2o.R`.